# Django Rest - Cant serialize items

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize nested relations, but got an error during create model from request: `'MeasureUnit' object has no attribute 'unit'`

What am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to create model `MeasureItem`, but got error in `MeasureUnit` somehow.

My models:

```
from django.db import models
from measure_unit.models import MeasureUnit
from main_user.models import MainUser

class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=15)
    current_code = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=15)

    title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    measure_units = models.ManyToManyField(MeasureUnit, through='MeasureItem', through_fields=('item', 'unit'), blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)

class MeasureItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasureUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
```

My serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Item, MeasureItem

class MeasureUnitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MeasureItem
        fields = ('id', 'unit')

class ItemAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    measure_units = MeasureUnitSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'code', 'current_code', 'title', 'description', 'measure_units')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        units_data = validated_data.pop('measure_units')
        item = Item.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for unit_data in units_data:
            try:
                measure_unit = unit_data['unit']
                MeasureItem.objects.create(unit=measure_unit, item=item)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
                return item
        return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeasureUnitSerializer` is ModelSerializer for `MeasureItem` model, but you use it for `MeasureUnit` model in `ItemAdminSerializer`:

```
measure_units = MeasureUnitSerializer(many=True)
```

Since MeasureUnit doesn't have `unit` field you see error. 
You could try to specify `source` argument of `measure_units` field:

```
measure_units = MeasureUnitSerializer(source='measureitem_set', many=True)
```

Comment: Thx for saving my day %)